# Can't find previous conversations in Lync 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm forced to use Lync 2010 & Outlook 2010 for work some latest days. Everything works well until I need to find previous conversations, and I got this:  [image: cant find previous conversations in Lync 2010]
Some try with Google and I got [this tutorial by Microsoft for fix](http://technet.Microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398806.aspx). But when I click on the link given in that tutorial for a patch I got this [image: cant download patch from Microsoft]
So I post this questions here to ask for help, If anyone know how to fix this problem, please do me a favor to say about how to fix it.

p/s: If it's a matter then I could ignore my lost conversations, I just need to save all my conversations from now on.

---

FYI
Still **CAN NOT** do this from Lync (find previous conversations) even when I've switched to
**Windows 7 Ultimate + Outlook 2010 + Lync 2010**
However, at least I can go to Outlook and search in **Conversation** folder to find something.

Comment: Lync messages history requires MS Exchange Server.

Comment: @dnbrv : of course I'm using Lync within my company Exchange server. The problem is Lync program on my PC can't do the "find prev conversation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but after few months, finally I could do this (find previous conversations)! **May be it's from many Window update I've installed.**
Just add an *answer* to increase my accept rate.